# Thread run and stop button control with python

Tags: python, multithreading

There are a total of A, B, and C threads, and A and B are threads that call back and receive data signals.

I want to implement a thread running and stop immediately based on receiving signal data.

1. If data is number 1, run C thread
2. If the data is number 2, immediately abort the C thread.
   (C thread 1 loop takes about 1 minute)

I want to implement a thread that can repeatedly perform steps 1 and 2 above.
(signal variable receives button signal through mobile phone)

What should I do?

```py
c = threading.Thread(target=test.main)

def call_back(signal):
    if signal == 1:
        c.start()  # start
    elif signal == 2:
        c.join()  # stop
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread helps?

Comment: I solved it thanks to that link.